# How to fix `AUTO_INCREMENT` error in my code

Tags: sql, derby, auto-increment, identity-column

I'm trying to resolve my error but often I see this error. help me to solve it.

```java
 public static void fetchDetails() throws SQLException
    {
        int i;
        Scanner scann = new Scanner(System.in);
        Connection c = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/AttendClass","ms","6079");         
        Statement st = c.createStatement();

        System.out.println("\n1.Civil\n2.CSE\n3.ECE\n4.EEE\n4.ICE\n5.IT\n6.MECH\n7.MBA\nChoose Your Department: ");
        ch = scann.nextInt();

        switch(ch)
        {
            case 1:
                dept = "CIVIL";
                String tbl1 = "CREATE TABLE "+dept+"(bno int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,one varchar(30),two varchar(30),three varchar(30),four varchar(30),five varchar(30),six varchar(30),seven varchar(30),eight varchar(30)),PRIMARY KEY (bno)";
                st.executeUpdate(tbl1); 
                ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery("select * from "+dept+"");
                 System.out.println("Enter the no. of students: ");
                 i = scann.nextInt();
```

I expect the output of auto increment the my table.

Comment: [As documented in the manual](http://db.apache.org/derby/docs/10.15/ref/rrefsqlj37836.html) Derby has no `auto_increment`. Use an identity column instead

Answer (score 1):

Here is how to increment your Primary Key
Code below is String Statement to create a Derby Database Table

```
String SQL_CreateCBBalance = "create table CBBalance ("
+ "MID    int not null generated always as identity "
+ "       (start with 100,increment by 1),"
+ "masterbalance  varchar(20),"
+ "primary key (MID))";
```